# Strange noise while dual mining - Claymore

Tags: ether, claymore

I have 2 MSI GTX 1070 8 GB. I tried dual mining ETH + Sia -- but when I dual mining I hear strange noise out of video card. When I mine just ETH there is no noise.

Can anyone tell me what I get that noise? is this dangerous for my cards? anyone else getting noise in dual mining?

Thanks  in advance

Comment: Mining using GPU is an intensive task, make sure that the GPU temperatures are fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing Coil whine. Totally normal for a gpu to create the noise depending on the load and power of the gpu